# AngularJS 1.5 Components printed before gets the controller values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-http, angularjs-components

I've a parent view with a parent controller, with 2 children component, each one with his own controller.

Something like this:

```
<section>     // Main Controller
  <table-users listusers="users"></table-users>     // Component Table User Controller
  <table-news listusers="users"></table-news>       // Component Table News Controller
</section>
```

The Main Controller executes a GET XHR request to an API (which takes about 1 or 2 seconds), and the response of that request is passed to the components.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.view')
    .component('tableUsers', {
      bindings: {
        listusers: '='
      },
      controller   : 'UsersTableController',
      controllerAs : 'vm',
      templateUrl  : 'whatever.html'

    });

})();
```

My problem is that the response is returned *after* the components is already printed.

So I got `vm.listusers = undefined`
and I have a `vm.listusers = [{},{}...]` object...

If I create a fake `vm.users` in the MainController everything works, so the problem is that GET returns the response too late.

I just created this sample case using GitHub API:
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Rem3veEcDD3p7h6omLW9)

Is there a way to tell the component to wait until this value is returned before printed in the DOM or something like that?

Comment: Hi @MarcusH ! thanks for your fast reply, but your plunkr link seems to be empty i just see the Hello plunkr ! template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Angular 1.5.3 we have access to some sweet methods one of these is called $postLink its the way we can basically mimic the linker function in a component and a way to essentially only write components.

```
    vm.$postLink = function() {
      $timeout(function() {
        vm.users = vm.listusers;
      })
    }
```

There is the one catch of the $timeout that I havent been able to get to work correctly without it. Anyways it says fire a digest cycle.

Some places to read about it [here](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2016/03/29/exploring-angular-1.5-lifecycle-hooks.html), [here](https://toddmotto.com/angular-1-5-lifecycle-hooks) and I also wrote about it [here](http://powdertothepeople.tv/2016/05/05/angular-component/)

Now having said all that why are u binding a value that is already "bound to the controller" just use the binding that already exists...

```
 angular
.module('app')
.component('tableUsers', {
  bindings: {
    listusers: '='
  },
  controller   : 'ComponentController',
  controllerAs : 'vm',
  template  : '<h1>{{vm.title}}</h1>'+
              '<p>{{vm.listusers}}</p>' +
              '<ul>' +
                '<li ng-repeat="user in vm.listusers">' +
                  '<strong>{{user.login}}</strong><span> - {{user.id}} </span>' +
                '</li>' +
              '</ul>'
});
```

No need to make vm.users = vm.listusers... its already bound to the controller, just use it...

Inside the source code for the component you will see that the bindToController line that we are familar with from directives defaults to the bindings array we pass it.

```
bindToController: options.bindings || {},
```

Components are all about removing that crappy boilerplate that directives forced upon us.

Also you can then take advantage as well of controllerAs naming that comes out of the box. No need to give it the meaningless name of vm in the template $ctrl is the "free" binding we are also given out of the box - I strongly advocate for its use.

```
 angular
.module('app')
.component('tableUsers', {
  bindings: {
    listusers: '<' // Use 1 way bindings to enforce uni-directional data flow
  },
  controller   : 'ComponentController',
  template  : '<h1>{{$ctrl.title}}</h1>'+
              '<p>{{$ctrl.listusers}}</p>' +
              '<ul>' +
                '<li ng-repeat="user in $ctrl.listusers">' +
                  '<strong>{{user.login}}</strong><span> - {{user.id}} </span>' +
                '</li>' +
              '</ul>'
});
```

Finally your [PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/C8c34lenUWkGjgk0pdOu?p=preview)

Comment: Hi Sten, i didn't know about $postLink method.
i added your code snippet to the component controller ( instead of the initial  ```vm.users = vm.listusers```  and added $timeout to the controller function parameters to be able to used it, but still doesn't work.

Can you detail more your answer ? or paste a link with my initial plunkr case fixed it ? would be much appreciated

Comment: Awesome !!
So in the component case you strongly recommend use $ctrl than vm, interesting and much cleaner :)

I saw you added the $scope param to the component controller function, but isn't need right ? i mean, i removed to check it and everything seems working :)

Comment: Shit, yeah the scope was from a watcher i placed inside to debug that everythign was indeed being passed down the chain. Yeah why not use $ctrl over vm!? in the controller I still like to user var vm = this. we can easily specify what needs to be "public" and what needs to just be a controller method. Also I think vm looks nicer in my IDE vs this. XD

Comment: totally agreed man, this helped me a lot ! thank you
I was checking and saw the require property, but seems to be redundant if you use 1 way binding '<' maybe just for directives purposes..